# How to Open the Android App by Clicking the OneSignal PushNotificatioin

Tags: wordpress, flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I integrated OneSignal Push Notification in my flutter android app I got notification. But The problem is When I click it means the app isn't opening. Please Anyone Suggest me to Fix this Issue.

I Expect to open the app automatically by clicking the notification without navigate to any pages.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your Flutter Android app opens automatically when a user clicks a OneSignal push notification, you need to handle the notification click event and take appropriate action. Here's how you can achieve this:

### Flutter Configuration:

Make sure you have configured your Flutter app to handle push notifications using the `flutter_local_notifications` package or a similar package that provides notification-handling capabilities.

### Handle Notification Click:

In your Flutter code, you should listen for notification click events and take action to open the app. Here's a simplified example using the `flutter_local_notifications` package:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureLocalNotifications();
  }

  void _configureLocalNotifications() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'),
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification);
  }

  Future<void> _onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    // Handle the notification click event here
    // Open the appropriate screen or perform desired action
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Notification Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Flutter App with Push Notifications'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Handle App Launch from Background:

If the user clicks the notification when the app is in the background or not running, you need to handle the app launch and navigate to the appropriate screen based on the notification's payload. This is usually done in the `_onSelectNotification` method.

### Configure OneSignal Notification Payload:

When sending notifications using OneSignal, make sure you include the necessary payload data that you can use to determine which screen to navigate to when the notification is clicked.

```dart
OneSignal.shared.postNotification(OSCreateNotification(
  playerIds: ['player_id_here'],
  content: 'Notification message',
  additionalData: {'screen': 'desired_screen'},
));
```

By handling the notification click event in your Flutter code and using the appropriate navigation methods, you can achieve the desired behavior of automatically opening the app when a OneSignal push notification is clicked.

Comment: @override
  void initState(){super.initState();onInitApp();}
  void onInitApp() {
    OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);
    OneSignal.shared.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission().then((accepted) {});
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result){Get.to(() => MyHomePage());});}This is the code that which i used in the main.dart file to implement the function to open the app by clicking the notificatoin. Can You Please Tell me what wrong in it